# How to generate a matrix with random entries and with constraints on row and columns?

Tags: python, matlab, matrix, julia

How to generate a matrix that its entries are random real numbers between zero and one inclusive with the additional constraint : The sum of each row must be less than or equal to one and the sum of each column must be less than or equal to one.

Examples:

```
matrix = [0.3, 0.4, 0.2;
          0.7, 0.0, 0.3; 
          0.0, 0.5, 0.1]
```

Comment: Matlab? Python? Julia? Which one?

Comment: I do not have preferences. At first, I put only `matrix` but then I said I should tag a programming language. Should I keep only one?

Comment: Well you probably need an algorithm, so you might drop them all. Anyway, you now have a python and a matlab solution, so you should stick with those now.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want a matrix that is *uniformly distributed* and fulfills those constraints, you probably need a *rejection method*. In Matlab it would be:

```
n = 3;
done = false;
while ~done
    matrix = rand(n);
    done = all(sum(matrix,1)<=1) & all(sum(matrix,2)<=1);
end
```

Note that this will be slow for large `n`.

Comment: Just noting the OPs tags: perhaps you should mention that this is not C++ ;)

Comment: Another option would be to generate the data element by element, generating `matrix(i,j)=rand()*(1-sum(matrix(i,1:j-1))` and the same for columns...

Comment: Oops. Multiple languages. Edited. About generating that way: the resulting distribution wouldn't be uniform on the space of matrices. Then again, not sure if the OP wants uniform

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for a Python way, this is simply a transcription of Luis Mendo's rejection method.  For simplicity, I'll be using NumPy:

```
import numpy as np
n = 3
done = False

while not done:
    matrix = np.random.rand(n,n)
    done = np.all(np.logical_and(matrix.sum(axis=0) <= 1, matrix.sum(axis=1) <= 1))
```

---

If you don't have NumPy, then you can generate your 2D matrix as a list of lists instead:

```
import random 
n = 3
done = False

while not done:

    # Create matrix as a list of lists
    matrix = [[random.random() for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]

    # Compute the row sums and check for each to be <= 1
    row_sums = [sum(matrix[i]) <= 1 for i in range(n)]

    # Compute the column sums and check for each to be <= 1
    col_sums = [sum([matrix[j][i] for j in range(n)]) <= 1 for i in range(n)]

    # Only quit of all row and column sums are less than 1
    done = all(row_sums) and all(col_sums)
```

Comment: @LuisMendo - NumPy is the easiest way to transition from MATLAB :D Divakar will tell you!  I'm also writing a solution without it.

Comment: I know, I know... Some day... :-)

Answer (score 3):

The rejection method will surely give you a uniform solution, but it might take a long time to generate a good matrix, especially if your matrix is large. So another, but more tedious approach is to generate each element such that the sum can only be 1 in each direction. For this you always generate a new element between 0 *and the remainder until 1*:

```
n = 3

matrix = zeros(n+1); %dummy line in first row/column
for k1=2:n+1
for k2=2:n+1
   matrix(k1,k2)=rand()*(1-max(sum(matrix(k1,1:k2-1)),sum(matrix(1:k1-1,k2))));
end
end

matrix = matrix(2:end,2:end)
```

It's a bit tricky because for each element you check the row-sum and column-sum until that point, and use the larger of the two for generating a new element (in order to stay below a sum of 1 in both directions). For practical reasons I padded the matrix with a zero line and column at the beginning to avoid indexing problems with `k1-1` and `k2-1`.

Note that as [@LuisMendo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33003153/how-to-generate-a-matrix-with-random-entries-and-with-constraints-on-row-and-col/33003449#comment53831707_33003194) pointed out, this will have a different distribution as the rejection method. But if your constraints do not consider the distribution, this could do as well (and this will give you a matrix from a single run).

Comment: But if the accumlated sum exceeds 1, that `(1-max(...))` will give a negative entry?

Comment: @LuisMendo, if I'm not mistaken, it can't. That's why the generation is so convoluted: you constrain each element to stay between 0 and 1-"sum of the previous guys in the row/column"

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, I agree