# Creating a 2d numpy array with certain constraints

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random, constraints

I would like to create a 2 dimensional numpy array `M` of size `n,n` (a square matrix `M` that is) with the following constraints:

1. The sum of each row equals to one
2. The elements of each row are all between 0 and 1
3. The value of row `i` that dominates is located at entry `M[i,i]`.

For example, for a square matrix it would be something like
`M = np.array([[0.88,0.12],[0.13,0.87]])`

4. (Bonus) Ideally I want the entries of each row to follow some Gaussian like distribution whose peak, for row `i`, is located at element `M[i,i]`.

In [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33003153/how-to-generate-a-matrix-with-random-entries-and-with-constraints-on-row-and-col)  a similar question is asked. However, playing with the responses there I was not able to find a way to do it. This is a search problem, and I do understand it might be formulated as an optimization problem. However, I am wondering if these constraints can satisfied without the need of some specialized solver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1) and 2):

```
M = np.random.rand(n,n)
x = M / M.sum(1, keepdims=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is easy, indeed. However, the 3d one is the tricky one (the "Bonus" should go to the fourth point).

Answer (score 0):

I subtract the number of columns from the number of rows per coordinate, and then use them to calculate the value of the Gaussian function, and finally multiply it by a random array and normalize it.

It may not be so random, but it has a high probability of meeting your requirements:

```
>>> size = 4
>>> ii, jj = np.indices((size, size))
>>> gaussian = np.exp(-((ii - jj) ** 2) / 2)
>>> result = np.random.normal(1, .1, gaussian.shape) * gaussian
>>> result /= result.sum(1, keepdims=True)
>>> result
array([[0.47556382, 0.38041462, 0.11953135, 0.02449021],
       [0.24805318, 0.4126681 , 0.26168636, 0.07759236],
       [0.10350016, 0.26245839, 0.37168771, 0.26235374],
       [0.02027633, 0.11892695, 0.31971733, 0.54107939]])
```